# How to prevent Ansible from merging host variables?

Tags: ansible

I have a host under two group names (in the example below). If `group_1` is called I want it to connect to it via ssh, but if `group_2` is called I want it to be a local connection. However, ansible seems to be merging the two hosts variables together even though they're in different groups? It's using a local connection for `group_1`. 
How can I prevent this?

```
[group_1]
example.com ansible_user=ansible ansible_ssh_private_key_file="{{ lookup('env','PATH_TO_KEYS') }}"/my.pem

[group_2]
example.com  ansible_port=8081 ansible_connection=local
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inventory hostname can be arbitrary but it is the key identifier for the host so the vars will aggregated as described here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable

We can use the arbitrary string combined with `ansible_host` to kind of game the system to do what you want. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-non-standard-ports

Also, note that the `ansible_connection=local` is going to execute code on your localhost without use of any connections or service daemon (ssh or otherwise) so the `ansible_port` is not necessary.

```
[group_1]
example_ssh ansible_host=example.com ansible_user=ansible ansible_ssh_private_key_file="{{ lookup('env','PATH_TO_KEYS') }}"/my.pem

[group_2]
example_local_8081 ansible_host=example.com  ansible_port=8081 ansible_connection=local
```